# How can I add borders in a emit bake or baked?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, render-border

I used emit to get this baked image, but I need to make borders with some margin/padding of the images like the image below.

EDITED:
The purpose itself is to be able to print each piece/section with a marked margin and then physically be able to be assembled (glued by the margins).

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help, thanks!

[This is how it should look]
[image]
(I added the red lines in photoshop, not in blender.)

UVs of the sphere...
[image]

[In this attempt, I duplicated the sphere, split it, extruded alogn, deleted the other faces, adjusted the seams and... it was offset from the previous uvs, so I won't be able to overlay them.]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cut these vertical edges with the knife, give another material to these faces:

[image]

Only keep one slice and duplicate and rotate it to rebuild the whole sphere:

[image]

Comment: oh, I hadn't thought of that, thanks, but those shapes are the seams of a sphere's mesh, I can't do an inset without damaging the mapping. If they were individual objects it would be great, thanks anyway.

Comment: so maybe do an outset?

Comment: there I added another image where you see the object and the uvs

Comment: The purpose itself is to be able to print each piece/section with a marked margin and then physically be able to be assembled (glued by the margins).

Comment: so maybe you could export the UV layout and draw your lines in an image editor software?

Comment: So far it's what I'm doing, I export the baked and then add borders in Photoshop, but I would like to achieve it with the blender.

Comment: I think your idea ( @moonboots ) could work if... I duplicate the sphere, break it into the UVs, do what you say, and then bake, I should be ready to overlay it with the previous one but... the UVs won't line up with the previous one :S

Comment: Please see my edit, maybe it's a way to do it?

Comment: almost... but those edges should not be inwards because part of the image would be cut off, those edges should be outwards.

Comment: so, do the same except it is outwards? but the faces will overlap

Comment: that's what I was thinking taking your idea, in fact I'm doing it, but I was just commenting that I think, I'm not sure... the result would be that the 2nd bake would not be aligned with the first one.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the bake thing, what do you need to bake?

Comment: These textures are generated from a bake emit (in render cycles), which in turn are generated using another projected UV, this is so that it generates the deformed divided texture exactly so that it can be assembled after printing on plastic.

Comment: See my proposition, make sure that the inner faces and the borders have a different material (picture for the inner faces, red color for the outer faces), once you've rebuilt the whole sphere, select the inner faces (select by material as they have their own material) and bake the previous version of your sphere?